# How to load ckeditor via requirejs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, requirejs

I'm having issues trying to load ckeditor via requirejs (I've tried converting the main ckeditor js file into individual modules but that has just caused all hell to break loose) and so I'm now checking to see if there is a very simple way to do this that I've missed.

I know requirejs allows you to load normal js scripts so maybe just loading the ckeditor.js file (un-edited, so it's still an IIFE/self-executing function) - would that work with requirejs or if you're using requirejs for loading modules, does the entire project then need to be module based?

Any help appreciated.

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, it seems I answered my own question here.

Instead of trying to break ckeditor down into modules I just used RequireJs to load the script in it's entirety.

```js
require(['require', 'dependancy-A', 'dependancy-B', 'dependancy-C'], function(require, A, B, C){

    // this = [object DOMWindow]
    // CKEDITOR_BASEPATH is a global variable
    this.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/ckeditor/';

    require(['/ckeditor/ckeditor'], function(){
        // Code to create a new editor instance
    });

});
```

```

Comment: This method doesn't list CKEditor as a dependancy of the module, and doesn't use RequireJS to load CKEditor either, instead falling back to (a pair of) JavaScript tags to load CkEditor. This means CKEditor may not be loaded by the time this module runs.

Answer (score 26):

Alternatively, you can create a RequireJS shim to load things in the correct order, and alias proper RequireJS module names to the CKEditor distribution files.

This means your module still declares it is dependant on CKEditor, which is a lot nicer than having it just show up by magic.

```
require.config({
shim: {
    'ckeditor-jquery':{
        deps:['jquery','ckeditor-core']
    }
},
 paths: {
    "jquery": '/javascript/jquery-1.7.1/jquery.min',
    'ckeditor-core':'/javascript/ckeditor-3.6.4/ckeditor',
    'ckeditor-jquery':'/javascript/ckeditor-3.6.4/adapters/jquery'
}
});
```

then in a module you can depend on ckeditor-jquery (or ckeditor-core for that matter, if you don't need the jQuery integration) and know it'll be available:

```
require(
[
    "jquery",
    "ckeditor-jquery"
],
function( _jquery_ ) {

    $('#editorContent2').ckeditor({
        customConfig : '',
        skin:'office2003'
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I knew the answer was going to be to shim it, but I was too lazy to think up how to do that properly. Thankfully, I didn't have to.

Comment: still not working for me... I get error saying the dependencies paths are wrong. any other helpful info you guys can give me? thanks

Comment: @Tom Chiverton, how do you get the css to load?

Comment: @CodeJunkie sounds like a different problem (you've not told CkEditor the correct paths maybe ?) so needs a different question

Comment: my framework was building secure urls that my css didn't have permission to access. Resolved, thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that:

```
var require = {
    "shim": {
        "path/foo/ckeditor/ckeditor": { "exports": "CKEDITOR" }
    }
};

define(['moduleX', 'path/foo/ckeditor/ckeditor'], function (x, ckeditor) { 

     ckeditor.editor.prototype.fooFunc = function() {

     };
});
```