# How to disable CKEditor automatic style and script loading?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm managing dependencies with RequireJS, but CKEditor upon first instantiation wants to load the config, style and language files. I can't find a way to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713194/how-to-load-ckeditor-via-requirejs) ?

```
require(['require', 'dependancy-A', 'dependancy-B', 'dependancy-C'], function(require, A, B, C){

    // this = [object DOMWindow]
    // CKEDITOR_BASEPATH is a global variable
    this.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/ckeditor/';

    require(['/ckeditor/ckeditor'], function(){
        // Code to create a new editor instance
    });

});
```

You can just remove plugins script with:

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font';
```

Comment: ok and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713194/how-to-load-ckeditor-via-requirejs ?