# use requirejs to load CKeditor.js after textarea tag

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ckeditor

CKeditor is a WYSIWYG editor, here is the [link](http://docs.cksource.com/).

The right way to load it is to include

```
<script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
...
```

in header, and put this tag in the body.

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
```

It works perfectly, but when I use require.js to do it. It is not working. Here is my main.js (entry point for require.js)

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery',
        ckeditor: 'ckeditor/ckeditor',
        domReady: 'domReady'
    },
    shim: {
        ckeditor: {
            deps: ['domReady']
        }

    }

});

require(['ckeditor'], function(ck){

});
```

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
    <head>
        <script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I am stuck here. Can anybody help me point out where I made mistake? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load ckeditor via requirejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713194/how-to-load-ckeditor-via-requirejs)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use 'domReady!' in a require expression. like the guides here

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload